# how can i read datasets in Weka?

Tags: weka

I want to use some of the datasets available at the website of the Weka to perform some
experiments with Neural Networks.

What do I have to do to read the data?

I downloaded the datasets and they were saved as .arff.txt so I deleted the extension of .txt to have only .arff. So I used this file as an ipnut but an error occurs.
Which is the right way to read data? 
Do I have to write code?

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: What error do you get?  Which  version of Weka are you using? List the file you used & I'll try & let you know if it works for me.  FYI, I won't be able to test this until later tonight.

Comment: 22:00:35: Unable to determine structure as arff (Reason: java.io.IOException: keyword @relation expected, read Token[<!--], line 2).
22:00:35: Interrupted
22:00:35: There was 1 error

Comment: this is the error, iam using the WEKA 3.7. , I don't know if is problem of the file or the procedure I follow to make the experiment

Comment: the file is the COCOMO81 dataset which is for the effort estimation  I found it on this website http://promisedata.org/?p=6

Comment: What is the exact name of the file you are using? coc81.arff, coc81_1_1.arff or coc81-dem.arff?

Comment: I tried now another file the Desharnais.arff and is working for the Neural Netowrks. I don't know which is the problem with the specific file. Thank you for your help . Now I have another question, when I open the results file, the only information I can get is about the attributes appearing at the left. Does Weka provide any information like Model Summary like the SPSS tool does?

Comment: If you have another question, then first try to find the answer on the Internet or Stack Overflow, otherwise please open a new question and I will try to answer it there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Weka 3.6.6 and coc81.arff opens just fine. You are using Weka 3.7.x, which is the development branch of Weka. I suggest that you [download](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) 3.6.6 or 3.6.7 (the latest stable release) and try to open the file again.

Comment: I was able to open data/coc81/coc81.arff in Weka 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

There is also another simple throw...
open your dataset file in excel in my case MS Excel2010, format fields intype.
and save as 'csv', 
then reload that csv file in the weka explorer and save on the local drive as arff format.
may be this help.